# Converting nested JSON file with duplicate keys to dataframe in Python

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

Assume the following snip of a JSON file to be flattened on Python.

```
{
  "locations" : [ {
    "timestampMs" : "1549913792265",
    "latitudeE7" : 323518421,
    "longitudeE7" : -546166813,
    "accuracy" : 13,
    "altitude" : 1,
    "verticalAccuracy" : 2,
    "activity" : [ {
      "timestampMs" : "1549913286057",
      "activity" : [ {
        "type" : "STILL",
        "confidence" : 100
      } ]
    }, {
      "timestampMs" : "1549913730454",
      "activity" : [ {
        "type" : "DRIVING",
        "confidence" : 100
      } ]
    } ]
  }, {
    "timestampMs" : "1549912693813",
    "latitudeE7" : 323518421,
    "longitudeE7" : -546166813,
    "accuracy" : 13,
    "altitude" : 1,
    "verticalAccuracy" : 2,
    "activity" : [ {
      "timestampMs" : "1549911547308",
      "activity" : [ {
        "type" : "ACTIVE",
        "confidence" : 100
      } ]
    }, {
      "timestampMs" : "1549912330473",
      "activity" : [ {
        "type" : "BIKING",
        "confidence" : 100
      } ]
    } ]
  } ]
}
```

The goal is to turn it into a flattened dataframe like this:

```
location_id timestampMs ... verticalAccuracy activity_timestampMs activity_activity_type ...
1           1549913792265   13               1549913286057        "STILL"
1           1549913792265   13               1549913730454        "DRIVING"
etc.
```

How would one do so given that the key 'activity' is repeated at different nest levels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using `json_normalize` ([documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html)), assuming the JSON snippet you posted is in a python dictionary named `d`.

```
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

# Build a list of paths to JSON fields that will end up as metadata
# in the final DataFrame
meta = list(js['locations'][0].keys())

# meta is now this:
# ['timestampMs',
# 'latitudeE7',
# 'longitudeE7',
# 'accuracy',
# 'altitude',
# 'verticalAccuracy',
# 'activity']

# Almost correct. We need to remove 'activity' and append
# the list ['activity', 'timestampMs'] to meta.
meta.remove('activity')
meta.append(['activity', 'timestampMs'])

# meta is now this:
# ['timestampMs',
# 'latitudeE7',
# 'longitudeE7',
# 'accuracy',
# 'altitude',
# 'verticalAccuracy',
# ['activity', 'timestampMs']]

# Use json_normalize on the list of dicts
# that lives at d['locations'], passing in
# the appropriate record path and metadata
# paths, and specifying the double 'activity_'
# record prefix.
json_normalize(d['locations'], 
               record_path=['activity', 'activity'], 
               meta=meta,
               record_prefix='activity_activity_')

   activity_activity_confidence activity_activity_type    timestampMs  latitudeE7  longitudeE7  accuracy  altitude  verticalAccuracy activity.timestampMs
0                           100                  STILL  1549913792265   323518421   -546166813        13         1                 2        1549913286057
1                           100                DRIVING  1549913792265   323518421   -546166813        13         1                 2        1549913730454
2                           100                 ACTIVE  1549912693813   323518421   -546166813        13         1                 2        1549911547308
3                           100                 BIKING  1549912693813   323518421   -546166813        13         1                 2        1549912330473
```

### Edit

If the `['activity', 'activity']` record path is sometimes missing, the above code will throw an error. The following workaround *should* work for this specific case, but is brittle and might be unacceptably slow depending on the size of your input data:

```
# Create an example by deleting one of the 'activity' paths 
# from the original dict
del d['locations'][0]['activity']

pd.concat([json_normalize(x, 
                          record_path=['activity', 'activity'] 
                                      if 'activity' in x.keys() else None, 
                          meta=meta, 
                          record_prefix='activity_activity_') 
           for x in d['locations']], 
          axis=0, 
          ignore_index=True,
          sort=False)

   accuracy  altitude  latitudeE7  longitudeE7    timestampMs  verticalAccuracy  activity_activity_confidence activity_activity_type activity.timestampMs
0        13         1   323518421   -546166813  1549913792265                 2                           NaN                    NaN                  NaN
1        13         1   323518421   -546166813  1549912693813                 2                         100.0                 ACTIVE        1549911547308
2        13         1   323518421   -546166813  1549912693813                 2                         100.0                 BIKING        1549912330473
```

Comment: Thank you @Peter! Marked this as right as it answers my question and works! However, when working with the full dataset I get KeyError: 'activity'.

Currently investigating what the problem could be.

Comment: The problem was easy to spot when I imported the JSON file on R. Apparently, not all 'locations' have 'activity' within them (that's the higher level 'activity' - which automatically includes the lower level 'activity'). Any ideas?

Comment: @Deuterium, thanks for accepting - interesting follow-up problem. I have edited a possible solution into the bottom of my answer, but am hitting on the limits of my experience with JSON.